# Mirror image plot with 2 different sets of data MATLAB. Plotxx but same axis in different directions

Tags: matlab, plot, label

[image]

I need to create a plot of the type shown in the photo above. I have a plot of x against y for a set of data, then I make another plot also against x and y but i essentially have them back to back. Any method is fine.

I tried looking into plotxx or similar problems but the issue was that the plot was either on top and also going from left to right, as opposed to right to left as I have here.

Found this and played with it, have made minimal progress, maybe there is a quick fix.

```
plot(rand(1,10));       %# Plot some random data
ylabel(gca,'scale 1');  %# Add a label to the left y axis
set(gca,'Box','off');   %# Turn off the box surrounding the whole axes
axesPosition = get(gca,'Position');          %# Get the current axes position
hNewAxes = axes('Position',axesPosition,...  %# Place a new axes on top...
            'Color','none',...           %#   ... with no background color
            'XLim',[0 10],...            %#   ... and a different scale
            'XAxisLocation','top',...  %#   ... located on the right
            'YTick',[],...               %#   ... with no x tick marks
            'Box','off');                %#   ... and no surrounding box
xlabel(hNewAxes,'scale 2');  %# Add a label to the right y axis
```

(edit was simply correcting a typo)